# Postfix email forwarding working for one address but not for another

Tags: postfix, webmin

I have Postfix configured to use MariaDB to hold data. Everything is managed through webmin.

This is what my forwardings table looks like (the first row is supposed to capture everything that's sent to an undefined alias):

| Source | Destination |
| --- | --- |
| @here.com | throwaway |
| george@here.com | alex@here.com |
| bob@here.com | alex@here.com |
| alex@here.com | mymailbox@gmail.com |

I just found out that emails sent to george@here.com end up in the throwaway local virtual mailbox, while those sent to bob@here.com are correctly forwarded to mymailbox@gmail.com.

As a test, I created a new alias (george2@here.com) and emails sent to this address are forwarded correctly to my gmail mailbox.

These aliases, and there are a bunch of them, are only defined in the database. Any idea how to even begin to figure out what's going on here?

Thanks!

EDIT: In case it helps, here's a sanitized excerpt from /var/log/maillog:

Email to george2@here.com (delivered):

```
Dec  5 08:40:31 ewr postfix/smtpd[3924]: connect from sonic304-21.consmr.mail.ne1.yahoo.com[66.163.191.147]
Dec  5 08:40:31 ewr postfix/smtpd[3924]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:127.0.0.1:8891: Connection refused
Dec  5 08:40:31 ewr postfix/smtpd[3924]: ED0124002D: client=sonic304-21.consmr.mail.ne1.yahoo.com[66.163.191.147]
Dec  5 08:40:32 ewr postfix/cleanup[3949]: ED0124002D: message-id=<1036364390.1285942.1670247629826@mail.yahoo.com>
Dec  5 08:40:32 ewr postfix/qmgr[4511]: ED0124002D: from=<redacted@yahoo.com>, size=4412, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  5 08:40:32 ewr postfix/smtpd[3924]: disconnect from sonic304-21.consmr.mail.ne1.yahoo.com[66.163.191.147]
Dec  5 08:40:34 ewr postfix/smtp[3931]: ED0124002D: to=<mymailbox@gmail.com>, orig_to=<george2@here.com>, relay=mail.redacted[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25, delay=2.1, delays=0.13/0/0.79/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4NQl6m6trfz9vNQ1)
Dec  5 08:40:34 ewr postfix/qmgr[4511]: ED0124002D: removed
```

Email to george@here.com (thrown away):

```
Dec  5 08:41:16 ewr postfix/smtpd[3924]: connect from sonic304-21.consmr.mail.ne1.yahoo.com[66.163.191.147]
Dec  5 08:41:16 ewr postfix/smtpd[3924]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:127.0.0.1:8891: Connection refused
Dec  5 08:41:17 ewr postfix/smtpd[3924]: 0BAA64002D: client=sonic304-21.consmr.mail.ne1.yahoo.com[66.163.191.147]
Dec  5 08:41:17 ewr postfix/cleanup[3949]: 0BAA64002D: message-id=<1536910314.1285298.1670247674741@mail.yahoo.com>
Dec  5 08:41:17 ewr postfix/qmgr[4511]: 0BAA64002D: from=<redacted@yahoo.com>, size=4402, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  5 08:41:17 ewr postfix/smtpd[3924]: disconnect from sonic304-21.consmr.mail.ne1.yahoo.com[66.163.191.147]
Dec  5 08:41:17 ewr postfix/pipe[3954]: 0BAA64002D: to=<throwaway@here.com>, orig_to=<george@here.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.39, delays=0.15/0/0/0.24, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Dec  5 08:41:17 ewr postfix/qmgr[4511]: 0BAA64002D: removed
```

Comment: Have you checked for leading or trailing whitespace in `Source`?

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about that possibility. Neither webmin nor phpmyadmin showed any extra space, so I exported the table to CSV and there is no extra white space anywhere in any of the rows in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I was mistyping the email alias I was using to test this.

I was 99% sure this was human error, but with only two hours of sleep in two days it's really easy to miss a typo.